# Ошибка при ajax запросе

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Хочу отправить сообщение на php файл а потом из php файла на почту без перезагрузки страницы.

```
var $ = jQuery;
$('body').on('submit', 'form:not(.no_js)', function (e) {

    var form = this;
    //show_preloder(form);
    //clear_error(form);

    var data = new FormData($(this).get(0));
    console.log(form);
    $.ajax({
        url: $(form).attr('action'),
        method: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        data: data,

        beforeSend: function (data) {
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data['redirect']) window.location.href = '//' + location.host + '' + data['redirect'];
            if (data['errors']) each_error(form, data['errors']);
            if (data['function']) eval(data['function']);
            console.log('success');
        },

        complete: function (data) {
            $(data)[0].reset();
            $("#zap_form")[0].reset();
            $(".form")[0].reset();
            $value[''];
            $('#zap_form').find('input:text, input:password, input:file, select, textarea').val('');
            $('#zap_form').find('input:radio, input:checkbox')
                .removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');
            console.log('success');
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

вводит вот эту ошибку

[image: вводит вот эту ошибку]

ругается на эту строку (отменно красным квадратом и стрелкой)

[image: ругается на эту строку (отменно красным квадратом и стрелкой)]

Comment: Вы можете спокойно посмотреть сами что у вас в `$("#zap_form")` и тем более в `$("#zap_form")[0]`.

Comment: прошу прошение я немного отредактировал скриншот на какую строку ругается (второй скриншот)

Comment: Опять же, вы и сами может посмотреть что у вас в `$(data)` и `$(data)[0]` . Мы вот без понятия что у вас там и почему там должно работать reset...... reset можно на html форме вызвать... а у вас наверняка json прилетает судя по dataType

Comment: То, что у вас в `$(data)[0]` у него, возможно есть свойство `reset`, но `reset` не функция. Проверить можно так `console.log(typeof $(data)[0].reset)`

Comment: ок сейчас проверю

Comment: {"function":"$('#modal__call').removeClass('active-modal'); $('#modal__thx').addClass('active-modal');"}  ответ получил это

Comment: а что вообще в `data` ?

Comment: тогда я не в том месте проверил сейчас ввел undifine

Comment: в data вводит объект

Comment: выложите его.....и опишите вообще что вы хотите получить с помощью тех строк... зачем вам там reset вызывать

Comment: хочу очищать форму при отправке данных на почту

Comment: {
    "0": {
        "readyState": 4,
        "responseText": "{\"function\":\"$('#modal__call').removeClass('active-modal'); $('#modal__thx').addClass('active-modal');\"}",
        "responseJSON": {
            "function": "$('#modal__call').removeClass('active-modal'); $('#modal__thx').addClass('active-modal');"
        },
        "status": 200,
        "statusText": "OK"
    },
    "length": 1
}

Comment: какую форму очищать? Тут в ответе явно не код очистки формы... тут код добавления и удаления классов у модальной формы.... у этого кода не может быть никакого метода `reset`. а вызывать функцию видимо можно как `data[0].responseJSON()`